# Pass Spring datasource to Javers to Audit DTOs

Tags: spring, javers

In My Spring Boot application, I would like to audit DTOs instead of entities and move audit logic to common library which will have @EnableAudit annotation to audit DTO at method level. If I am using JaversBuilder.javers().build(); in common library I would not be able to commit data as it would not know anything of datasource.

I want to create Javers instance in my application and pass datasource to it and then pass Javers instances to common library to perform commit. Is there anyway in Spring boot application to create Javers instance and associat datasource to it which will be used at the time of commit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take `javers-spring-boot-starter`, you will get a Javers instance created as a Spring bean. It will be connected to your database and ready-to-use. See https://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I was able to resolve that.Is Javers build to support Auditing for DTOs as well and not just entities?. In our application we are trying to audit DTOs more flat structure and I am able to do that but it does not give me an option to have parent child relation to fetch history of all child records based on parent id. Also, Did not find any solution yet for how to audit field level update in Javers and not updating complete DTO/entity.

Comment: I don't understand your question. DTO is just an object. You can map it to Javers Entity or ValueObject.

Comment: Yeah I am able to commit dto directly and do an audit on it. But, if if am doing partial update for one or 2 field and not passing the full object Javers consider it all missing fields as a change and put it in changed fields column. How can I tell Javers about partial update and only 1 field changed ?

Comment: you can't, there is no such feature. My personal opinion about DTO's - they are clutter, get rid of them and things would become simpler